# Induced $G$-module - help with interpretation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

My lecture book *Algebra Vol. 2* by Cohn defines the induced $G$-module in the following way:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ an consider a right $H$-module $U$. From it we can form a right $G$-module
> $$\tag{1}
> \text{ind}_H^GU=U^G =U\bigotimes_HkG
> $$
> called the *induced* $G$-module

He then writes the following:

> The subspace $U\otimes H=\{u\otimes 1|u\in U\}$ of $U^G$ is an $H$-module in a natural way: for any $h\in H$ we have $(u\otimes 1)h=uh\otimes 1$. More generally we can define the subspace $U\otimes Ha=\{u\otimes a|u\in U\}$ of $U^G$ as an $H^a$-module, where $H^a=a^{-1}Ha$, by the rule
> $$\tag{3}
> (u\otimes a)x=uaxa^{-1}\otimes a\quad \text{for }x\in H^a.
> $$

**Question**: I assume that $U\otimes H$ is really $U\otimes kH$ (where $kH$ is the group algebra), which consists of elements of the form $u\otimes h$. I think the reason why we can write it as $U\otimes H=\{u\otimes 1|u\in U\}$ is that
$$\tag{2}
u\otimes h=u\otimes h\cdot 1=uh\otimes 1=u'\otimes 1,
$$
is that true? Also, the reason why we have $(u\otimes 1)h=uh\otimes 1$ is that because we consider $kH$ strictly a left module in this case?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: @Shaun, I have edited the question.